# Unable to install Mac OS X 'Yosemite' on MBP when trying to erase harddrive ; "erase process has failed."

Tags: macos, bootcamp, install

New to using mac os. I was attempting in installing Mac OS X 'Yosemite' on a mid 2010 macbook pro.

[Earlier before I started the whole process, I accidentally deleted everything (main harddrive) from disk utility including the bootcamp.]

I created a bootable USB with Yosemite on it, during the process, at the part where I am suppose to erase the main harddrive, I ran into "erase process has failed." = unable to erase the harddrive.

I've tried  first aid, erasing and etc = "erase process has failed"

[After watching this video; youtube.com/watch?v=o6s4GZWG7M0
I noticed that I am missing "Bootcamp"]

1) How do I erase my hard drive if I keep getting "erase process has failed" when I attempt to?

2) Does not having a bootcamp underneath my hard drive disallow me from erasing my main hard drive?

[EDIT]

Adding photos as requested by Monomeeth in comments:

- [Booting options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DP3v.jpg)
- [Upon boot from USB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IHl0.jpg)
- [Disk Utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID8U7.jpg)
- [Erasing options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGfMl.jpg)
- [Attempting to erase HD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIOEZ.jpg)

  [EDIT 2]

Additional images; 
I'm able to successfully erase the "2nd" HD but when I attempt to erase my main HD it fails.

- [Attempting to erase "2nd" HD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcQRr.jpg)
- [Successfully erase "2nd" HD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiRF0.jpg)
- [Return to erase main HD = fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7rlf.jpg)

  [EDIT 3]

ran command: `diskutil partitionDisk disk0 1 GPT HFS+ Mac_HD 100%`

- [Resulted in "Error: -69888: Couldn't unmount disk"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFcbz.jpg)

  [EDIT 4]

ran command: `diskutil list`

- [disk0 to disk12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcjOy.jpg)
- [disk 12 to disk15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaqTX.jpg)

  [EDIT 5]

ran command: `diskutil unmountDisk force diskX`

- ["Forced unmount of disk0 failed: at least one volume could not be unmounted"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxnQU.jpg)

/

ran command: `sudo diskutil unmountDisk force disk0`

- [""sudo command not found"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXtby.jpg)

  [EDIT 7]

Attempted to recreate a bootable USB with Yosemite on it, which was successful 
But

Still wasn't able to format internal HD.

Skipped to step 6

- [OS X utilities screen still says "Reinstall" instead of Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgMga.jpg)
- [There's no option to select Internal disk after selecting Reinstall OS X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph7EZ.jpg)
- Returned to disk utility and sucessfully formatted underneath my internal HD "2nd";

  [Erase Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w8uo.jpg)

  [Successfully erased "2nd"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X5zv.jpg)
- ["2nd" disk then showed up as an option to reinstall yosemite on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXm6e.jpg)
- [Attempted to reinstall, entered Apple ID and "this item is temporarily unavailable appeared again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma76Y.jpg)

Comment: **Possible duplicate of [Unable to install Yosemite using USB due to "erase process has failed"](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256713/unable-to-install-yosemite-using-usb-due-to-erase-process-has-failed) — Please don't repost your questions.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46714/discussion-on-question-by-johnny-unable-to-install-mac-os-x-yosemite-on-mbp-wh).

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to question 2**

No, not having Bootcamp does not prevent you from formatting the Mac's internal drive. In fact, the great majority of Mac owners do not have Bootcamp installed. Bootcamp is simply a tool released by Apple that allows Mac owners to install and boot their Macs natively into a Microsoft Windows installation. This happens alongside an existing macOS installation, but does not allow you to run Windows and macOS concurrently. It is a good option if you need to run Windows programs that are CPU-intensive in nature and don't lend themselves to working well in a virtual machine (such as ones set up with Parallels or VMWare Fusion).

**Answer to question 1**

I've looked at the photos I asked you to post and the second option after booting up from the USB should be Install OS X, ***not*** Reinstall OS X. This implies to me that you're USB is not in fact bootable because the 'Reinstall' option would normally appear when booting from the Recovery partition.

Can you try choosing the Reinstall OS X option instead to see whether you're able to successfully install a version of OS X. Let us know how you go.

Also, the photo of the error you get provides a lot more information. Basically the reason you can't erase the drive is because it can't be unmounted. This tells us a lot more about what may be going on, so if choosing the Reinstall OS X option gives you no joy then we've got more info to work with.

**[EDIT]**

Since you're unable to unmount the internal drive, and since the various terminal commands haven't worked, I strongly suspect that my earlier suspicion is correct - that your 'bootable' USB is in fact not bootable. Your question doesn't detail how you created the bootable USB, so let's start again using these steps:

1. Recreate your bootable USB. Since you're limited to doing this on
   Windows, follow the steps in this [article](http://pureinfotech.com/make-bootable-usb-mac-os-x-windows/).
2. Plug the USB into your Mac.
3. Switch the Mac on and immediately press the <kbd>Option</kbd> key.
4. When you see the choice of drives, select the USB.
5. Once the OS X Utilities window appears, select Disk Utility.
6. Try to erase your internal drive and see if you're now able to erase the disk. If unsuccessful take note of the error message etc. Regardless, go to the next step.
7. Exit Disk Utilities and select Install OS X.
8. Follow the steps to install OS X.

If you fail at either (or both) steps 6 and/or 8, please report back with what happens.

Comment: Oh okay, that would make sense. But how come I am unable to erase my hard drive?

Comment: That's exactly what we need to determine. When you get a chance, can you please take a photo of the following and add them to your question: (1) the MBP screen **after** it's finished booting from your USB but **before** you do anything; (2) the MBP screen **just before** you click on Erase; and, (3) the MBP screen **showing the error** after failing to erase the HD.

Comment: Added to comments underneath my post.

Comment: Can you confirm that when you are presented with the Booting option that you are actually selecting the USB disk (i.e. you are not selecting the Recovery option)? If you've been selecting the Recovery disk, try selecting the USB disk and let us know how you go.

Comment: I can confirm that i've been selecting the USB disk.

Comment: I have updated my answer to address Q1. Let me know how you go.

Comment: Okay thanks so far, I've tried the reinstall options many times, after I input my apple id it says " this item is temporarily unavailable"  which ultimately resulted in me attempting to reinstall os x by a bootable usb.

Comment: Once you've booted and see the OS X Utilities window you also have a Utilities menu. From there you should be able to launch the Terminal. Do this and enter the following command and report back with the result: _sudo diskutil unmountDisk force disk0_

Comment: I ran 'sudo diskutil unmountDisk force disk0' but the output was "sudo command not found"

Comment: I have edited my answer to Q1. Let me know how you go.

Comment: Great I'm trying to recreate my bootable drive,
after step 7 (in the cmd section) in the tutorial a separate windows pop up asks if i'd like to format my usb. I've select no and continued to the transmac. Would that be the correct thing to do?

Comment: I haven't ever had to do this (have always had multiple Macs around), but know of others who have. If it was me I would actually select Yes. If things don't work out you can redo it all and select No next time.